# Error compiling libvirt-php on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, virtualization, libvirt

i am trying to setup libvirt-php in my ubuntu server to do some test with the PHP API.
I am following this procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install libvirt-dev xsltproc libxml2-dev libxml2  
cd ~ 
git clone git://libvirt.org/libvirt-php.git libvirt-php  
cd libvirt-php  
sudo sh autogen.sh  
sudo ./configure  
sudo make  
sudo make install  
sudo service apache2 restart
```

i also installed php5-dev and xmllint package for ubuntu, but when i go to the 7 line: make i get these errors:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/libvirt-php'
Making all in tools
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/libvirt-php/tools'
gcc -Wall -o generate-api-docs generate-api-docs.c
./generate-api-docs ../src/libvirt-php.c ../docs/api-reference.html.in
Documentation has been generated successfully
./generate-api-docs --private ../src/libvirt-php.c ../docs/dev-api-reference.html.in
Documentation has been generated successfully
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/libvirt-php/tools'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/libvirt-php/src'
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -fpic -DCOMPILE_DL_LIBVIRT=1 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -c -o libvirt-php.o libvirt-php.c -I/usr/include/libxml2    -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
libvirt-php.c: In function ‘zm_startup_libvirt’:
libvirt-php.c:1149:2: error: ‘VIR_DOMAIN_VCPU_GUEST’ undeclared (first use in this function)
libvirt-php.c:1149:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
libvirt-php.c: In function ‘zif_libvirt_domain_get_metadata’:
libvirt-php.c:3240:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘virDomainGetMetadata’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
libvirt-php.c:3240:6: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
libvirt-php.c: In function ‘zif_libvirt_domain_set_metadata’:
libvirt-php.c:3285:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘virDomainSetMetadata’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
libvirt-php.c: In function ‘zif_libvirt_connect_get_soundhw_models’:
libvirt-php.c:4135:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
libvirt-php.c: In function ‘zif_libvirt_connect_get_nic_models’:
libvirt-php.c:4064:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
libvirt-php.c: In function ‘zif_libvirt_domain_get_screenshot_api’:
libvirt-php.c:3564:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘system’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
libvirt-php.c: In function ‘zif_libvirt_image_create’:
libvirt-php.c:2172:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘system’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
make[2]: *** [build] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/libvirt-php/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/libvirt-php'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

so i cannot compile. 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The require version wrote in git://libvirt.org/libvirt-php seems incorrect

It shows `LIBVIRT_REQUIRED=0.6.2`, but in version 0.9.8 which Ubuntu 12.04 using, variable `virDomainGetMetadata` and `VIR_DOMAIN_VCPU_GUEST` are not defined, which led to this error.

(If you want query what you libvirt-dev version is, type  $`dpkg-query -s libvirt-dev`)

You can try this:

1. Upgrade your Ubuntu

   Latest version of Ubuntu supports new libvirt-dev that have variable `virDomainGetMetadata`

   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt
2. Use libvirt-php 0.4.8

   I use this to solve the problem, but another problem arises out that it does not support  `libvirt_domain_get_metadata`.

   The following steps show how to use libvirt-php 0.4.8:

   Visit http://libvirt.org/php/downloads.html

   ```
   $wget http://libvirt.org/sources/php/libvirt-php-0.4.8.tar.gz
   $tar -xvf libvirt-php-0.4.8.tar.gz
   $cd libvirt-php-0.4.8
   $./configure
   $make
   ```

   Check there are not another problem then

   ```
   $sudo make install
   $sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: I found an better and easier alternative: I added this https://launchpad.net/~metacloud/+archive/libvirt-1.2.2 ppa (it contains libvirt 1.2.2) and after `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` I was able to compile it